# LIBSVM gives same prediction for samples of untrained class. Why?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm, prediction

I have trained an SVM on two classes. One is that of genuine user samples. The second is many negative samples of equal sample size to that of the genuine user. I have tested this system on class that has **not** been used for training. The results are interesting and I cannot explain them; I don't know whether this is expected, an SVM issue or something different.

```
(0:0.9104172110162648)(1:0.08958278898373527)(Actual:1.0 Prediction:0.0)
(0:0.9104172110162648)(1:0.08958278898373527)(Actual:1.0 Prediction:0.0)
(0:0.9104172110162648)(1:0.08958278898373527)(Actual:1.0 Prediction:0.0)
(0:0.9104172110162648)(1:0.08958278898373527)(Actual:1.0 Prediction:0.0)
(0:0.9104172110162648)(1:0.08958278898373527)(Actual:1.0 Prediction:0.0)
(0:0.9104172110162648)(1:0.08958278898373527)(Actual:1.0 Prediction:0.0)
(0:0.9104172110162648)(1:0.08958278898373527)(Actual:1.0 Prediction:0.0)
(0:0.9104172110162648)(1:0.08958278898373527)(Actual:1.0 Prediction:0.0)
(0:0.9104172110162648)(1:0.08958278898373527)(Actual:1.0 Prediction:0.0)
(0:0.9104172110162648)(1:0.08958278898373527)(Actual:1.0 Prediction:0.0)
(0:0.9104172110162648)(1:0.08958278898373527)(Actual:1.0 Prediction:0.0)
(0:0.9104172110162648)(1:0.08958278898373527)(Actual:1.0 Prediction:0.0)
(0:0.9104172110162648)(1:0.08958278898373527)(Actual:1.0 Prediction:0.0)
(0:0.9104172110162648)(1:0.08958278898373527)(Actual:1.0 Prediction:0.0)
(0:0.9104172110162648)(1:0.08958278898373527)(Actual:1.0 Prediction:0.0)
(0:0.9104172110162648)(1:0.08958278898373527)(Actual:1.0 Prediction:0.0)
(0:0.9104172110162648)(1:0.08958278898373527)(Actual:1.0 Prediction:0.0)
```

Above is an example of the sort of output I get for different samples of an untrained and unseen class. It's exactly the same for each sample. I would expect them to be closer to class 1.0, and I would also expect at least a change in the probabilities!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you cross validated your models' performance at all? Have you done a grid search for the hyper parameters?

Your output could potentially be easy explained as  poor execution of Machine Learning. If you are using the RBF kernel, and its width is too small, then the only factor that will contribute to a classification decision is the bias term. The bias term, by its nature, is the same for all inputs. Thus, you would get all the same outputs exactly (or almost) for all unseen test data (unless it was very very close to a training datum).

I can't say for sure this is what happened without knowing more details about your data and what you actually did. But this seems a likely scenario.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this.